# Is the four-jerk time-like or space-like?

Tags: special-relativity, jerk

In the paper [Dynamics of a Charged Particle](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.4614) the author claims after equation (10):

> However, this equation is mathematically inconsistent because both $\dot v^\mu$ and $\dot F^\mu$ are spacelike fourvectors, i.e. are perpendicular to the velocity $v^\mu$, while $\ddot v^\mu$ is not.

I don't believe this is correct since the time component of the four-acceleration is zero in the proper frame. Differentiating this wrt the proper time will again give a zero time component for the proper four-jerk giving another space-like four vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question "Is the four-jerk time-like or space-like?" is addressed by a paper by Russo and Townshend ("Relativistic kinematics and stationary motions", 9 October 2009,
Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical, Volume 42, Number 44 - https://doi.org/10.1088/1751-8113/42/44/445402 - preprint at  https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.4243 ).

> In view of these observations, it seems remarkable that the relativistic generalization of
>   jerk, snap, etc. has attracted almost no attention in more than a century since the foundation
>   of special relativity. It might be supposed that this is because there is little new to relativistic
>   kinematics once one has defined the D-acceleration A, in a D-dimensional Minkowski spacetime,
>   as the proper-time derivative of the D-velocity U:
>   $$A =\frac{dU}{d\tau}=\gamma \frac{dU}{dt},\qquad \gamma= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 − v^2}} . \qquad(1.2) $$
>   In particular, it is natural to suppose that one should define the relativistic jerk as $J = \frac{dA}{d\tau}$.
>   However, J is not necessarily spacelike.
>   This was pointed out in our previous paper [3] and it
>   led us to define the relativistic jerk as
>   $$\Sigma = J − A^2U , \qquad J = dA/d\tau.\qquad (1.3)$$
>   Observe that $U\cdot\Sigma ≡ 0$, which implies that $\Sigma$ is spacelike if non-zero.
>   
> $\qquad$
>   Following the posting in the archives of the original version of this paper, it was brought to
>   our attention that relativistic jerk arises naturally in the context of the Lorentz-Dirac equation,...

Comment: +1 Interesting, but it's a pity the paper is about branes, which makes the paper difficult to understand for me and probably the OP as well.